# How to fetch data from a nested array?

Tags: android, json, jsonparser

I have to fetch the value from an array nested inside another array. I can fetch values from the first array but not able to fetch values from the second array.

I am able to read the values from the main array but I am unable to read the values from the array which is nested inside it.

```
JSONObject jsono = new JSONObject(res);
JSONArray jarray = jsono.getJSONArray("data");

for (int i = 0; i < jarray.length(); i++)
{
  JSONObject object = jarray.getJSONObject(i);

  JSONArray jarray1 = object.getJSONArray("comments_data");

  for (int j = 0; j < jarray1.length(); j++)
  {
    JSONObject object1 = jarray1.getJSONObject(j);

    String Namee = object1.getString("username");
    String Ratingg = object1.getString("rating");
    String Commentt = object1.getString("comment");

    Comments comments1 = new Comments();

    comments1.setUsername(Namee);
    comments1.setRating(Ratingg);
    comments1.setComments(Commentt);
    comments1.setProfileimage(R.drawable.fav);

    commentsList.add(comments1);
  }
}
```

And this is my json.

```
{
    "status": "success",
    "msg": " Menu Details",
    "data": [
        {
            "id": "1",
            "rest_id": "1",
            "menu_rate": "100",
            "collection_time": "2:22pm",
            "quantity_left": "3",
            "food_type": "veg",
            "img1": "",
            "img2": "",
            "img3": "",
            "date": "",
            "menu_name": "",
            "comments_data": [
                {
                    "id": "20",
                    "user_id": "127",
                    "res_id": "1",
                    "comment": "shreyansh s",
                    "date": "0000-00-00 00:00:00",
                    "rating": "0.0",
                    "username": "lucky",
                    "userimage": "123"
                },
                {
                    "id": "19",
                    "user_id": "126",
                    "res_id": "1",
                    "comment": "das",
                    "date": "0000-00-00 00:00:00",
                    "rating": "3.0",
                    "username": "shrey srivastava",
                    "userimage": "123"
                },
                {
                    "id": "18",
                    "user_id": "126",
                    "res_id": "1",
                    "comment": "",
                    "date": "0000-00-00 00:00:00",
                    "rating": "3.0",
                    "username": "shrey srivastava",
                    "userimage": "123"
                },
                {
                    "id": "17",
                    "user_id": "126",
                    "res_id": "1",
                    "comment": "sakjbdkjasbk",
                    "date": "0000-00-00 00:00:00",
                    "rating": "3.0",
                    "username": "shrey srivastava",
                    "userimage": "123"
                },
                {
                    "id": "16",
                    "user_id": "107",
                    "res_id": "1",
                    "comment": "hello",
                    "date": "0000-00-00 00:00:00",
                    "rating": "5",
                    "username": "shreyansh",
                    "userimage": ""
                },
                {
                    "id": "15",
                    "user_id": "107",
                    "res_id": "1",
                    "comment": "hello",
                    "date": "0000-00-00 00:00:00",
                    "rating": "5",
                    "username": "shreyansh",
                    "userimage": "123"
                },
                {
                    "id": "14",
                    "user_id": "107",
                    "res_id": "1",
                    "comment": "hello",
                    "date": "0000-00-00 00:00:00",
                    "rating": "5",
                    "username": "shreyansh",
                    "userimage": "123"
                },
                {
                    "id": "6",
                    "user_id": "82",
                    "res_id": "1",
                    "comment": "good",
                    "date": "0000-00-00 00:00:00",
                    "rating": "",
                    "username": "jaim",
                    "userimage": "google.com"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: what is "JSONObject"? which package are you using?

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9606629/5167909

Comment: you can consider working with more friendly packages, such as org.codehaus.jettison.json (jettison.jar) or json-simple.jar... LMK if that helps a bit

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 1):

Note carefully how you JSON is built.

First, you have to query for "data". You get JSON-Array. So you traverse it by the indices.

Hence, you query for the specific index in "data" (you can use a loop, of course).

For each iteration, you get a JSONObject, and in it you query for "comments_data".

```
String json = "{ \"status\": \"success\", \"msg\": \" Menu Details\", \"data\": [ { \"id\": \"1\", \"rest_id\": \"1\", \"menu_rate\": \"100\", \"collection_time\": \"2:22pm\", \"quantity_left\": \"3\", \"food_type\": \"veg\", ...

JSONObject object = new JSONObject(json);

JSONObject jarray1 = jarray_data.getJSONObject(0);
JSONArray comments = jarray1.getJSONArray("comments_data");
```